# If [x]+[2x]+[3x]+[4x]=96 solve & find x. [x]= greatest integer

Tags: number-theory, functions

If [x]+[2x]+[3x]+[4x]=96 
solve & find x.
[x]= greatest integer

Comment: x -1 < [x] $\le x.   2x-1 <[2x] $\le$ 2x, etc.  So 10x -4 < 96 $\le $ 10x so x-.4 < 9.6 $\le $ x.  So 9.6 $\le $ x < 10.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Let $f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor 2x\rfloor+\lfloor 3x\rfloor+\lfloor 4x\rfloor$. It’s clear that $f$ is non-decreasing. Moreover, $f(9)=90$ and $f(10)=100$, so all solutions must lie strictly between $9$ and $10$. This means that $\lfloor x\rfloor$ will certainly be $9$, while $\lfloor 2x\rfloor$ will be either $18$ or $19$, depending on whether $x<9.5$ or not. If you extend this kind of reasoning, you shouldn’t have too much trouble finishing the solution.

Comment: It may also be helpful to note the function "jumps" only at integer multiples of $\frac{1}{12}$

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $a-1 <[a]\le a $.

So

$x + 2x + 3x +4x -4 < 96 \le x+2x+3x+4x $.

Solve for $x$.

$10x -4 < 96 \le 10x $

$-100 < -10x \le -96$

$9.6 \le x < 10$

But $[9.6] +[2*9.6]+[3*9.6]+[4*9.6]=9+19+28+38=94$.  We must increase by 2 so $3x \ge 29$ and $4x \ge 39$ so $x \ge 9.75$

So $9.75 \le x < 10$

====

Perhaps more directly:

By archimedean principal there exists and integer $n$ such that $n \le x < n +1$ and we call $[x] = n$ and we know $n-1 < [x] = n < x$.

Likewise there is an $i_2$ such that $n + i_2/2 \le x <n + (i_2 + 1)/2$ where $i_2 = 0$ or $2$.  Which means $2n + i_2 \le 2x < 2n + (i_2 + 1)$ so $[2x] = 2n + i_2$.

And $2x - 1 < [2x] = 2n + i_2 \le 2x < 2n + i_2 + 1$.

So following the same argume we know there are $i_2 = 0,1;i_3 = 0,1,2; i_4 = 0,1,2,3$ such that

$x - 1 < n=[x] \le x < n + 1$

$2x - 1 < 2n + i_2 = [2x] \le 2x < 2n + i_2 + 1$

$3x - 1 < 3n + i_3 = [3x] \le 3x < 3n + i_3 + 1$

$4x - 1 < 4n + i_3 = [4x] \le 4x < 4n + i_4 + 1$

so $x + 2x + 3x + 4x -4 < n+ 2n + 3n + 4n + i_2 + i_3 + i_4 = [x]+[2x]+[3x]+[4x] = 96 \le x + 2x + 3x + 4x$ i.e.

$10x - 4 < 10n +(i_2+i_3+i_4)=96 \le 10x$ so

$9.6 \le x < 10$ so $n = 9$, $i_2 = 1$, $i_3 = 1$ or $2$, $i_4 = 2$ or $3$. But $i_2 + i_3 + i_4 = 6$ so $i_3 + i_4 = \{1,2\} + \{2,3\} = 5$ so $i_2 = 1$ and $i_3 = 2$ and $i_4 = 3$

So $9 \le x < 10$ and $9.5 \le x < 10$ and $9 2/3 \le x < 10$ and $9.75 \le x < 10$

So $x \in [9.75,10)$

Comment: The true lower bound is 9.75.

Comment: There's a little gap in your understanding of "floor functions". No offense

Comment: How so? Does floor mean largest integer less than or equal. So [a] $\le $ a < [a] + 1, which is equivalent to a-1 < [a] $\le $ a.  Do you deny any of that?

Comment: Hmm, yes, you're right.  I need to take into account if [na] can't all be the maximum distance less than na so although 9.6 is a lower bound it isn't the least lower bound.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor 2x\rfloor+\lfloor 3x\rfloor+\lfloor 4x\rfloor
$.

We can see that
$9 < x < 10$
since
$f$ is non-decreasing,
$f(9)
= 90$,
and
$f(10)
= 100
$.

Suppose
$x
=9+\frac{k+z}{12}
$
where
$k \in \mathbb{N},
1 \le k \le 11
$
and
$0 \le z < 1$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(x)
&=f(9+\frac{k+z}{12})\\
&=\lfloor 9+\frac{k+z}{12}\rfloor+\lfloor 2(9+\frac{k+z}{12})\rfloor
+\lfloor 3(9+\frac{k+z}{12})\rfloor+\lfloor 4(9+\frac{k+z}{12})\rfloor\\
&=9+\lfloor 18+\frac{k+z}{6})\rfloor
+\lfloor 27+\frac{k+z}{4})\rfloor+\lfloor 36+\frac{k+z}{3})\rfloor\\
&=90+\lfloor \frac{k+z}{6}\rfloor
+\lfloor \frac{k+z}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{k+z}{3}\rfloor\\
&=90+\lfloor \frac{k}{6}\rfloor
+\lfloor \frac{k}{4}\rfloor+\lfloor \frac{k}{3}\rfloor\\
&= 90 \qquad\text{if } k \le 2\\
&= 91 \qquad\text{if } k =3\\
&= 92 \qquad\text{if } 4\le k \le 5\\
&= 94 \qquad\text{if } 6\le k \le 7\\
&= 95 \qquad\text{if }  k = 8\\
&= 96 \qquad\text{if } 9 \le k\le 11\\
\end{array}
$

The solutions are,
therefore
$9\frac{3}{4}
\le x
< 10
$.

Comment: Interestingly, this is the answer Wolfy gets.